# How we can handle child categories having multiple parent category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose if i have a menu like HOME| RECIPES| VIDEOS | CHEFS

And in (recipes Tab) i am showing some categories and sub-categories. The same categories and sub-categories i want in videos tab.Like what i want is: i would assign some videos post to the same category and some normal post to the same category.When i go on the site and come from Recipes Tab and click some category(Can we get the value of parent tab menu that we are clicking this category , and coming from that tab). is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are mistaken , you can not create child category in such a way that having multiple parents. It is not allowed in wordpress. You have to create seperate category for both the parents having same name but slug-name differently.

Thanks